# So how much did Mileva Maric contribute to Einstein's work?

Tags: einstein

I don't believe in the ridiculous conspiracy theories that she was the true founder of relativity and Einstein stole credit from her or any of that

but did she play a role in anyway helping him? someone said that before he met her he didn't have a single peer review publication?

how much did she help Einstein?

Comment: The question mentions peer review. In this regard, note that almost none of Einstein's publications were peer reviewed, as this was not the practice at the time (nor until sometime post WWII was it standard practice). There is a famous story about his angry reaction when in 1936 the Physical Review sent one of his articles to a reviewer (who moreover found errors in it). Details are easily found in the literature.

Comment: I am guessing this is prompted by Harris Walker's speculations? Most Einstein scholars do not take him seriously, and again, this is [well-detailed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mileva_Mari%C4%87#Debate_over_collaboration_with_Einstein). [Gagnon](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/the-forgotten-life-of-einsteins-first-wife) is a rare exception. As for peer review, see [How did the publication feat of Einstein's four 1905 Annus Mirabilis papers get through peer review?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5886/55) Hint: there was none.

Comment: so how much would you say she contributed to his work?

Comment: We try to avoid offering personal opinions here, you can read what scholars say and form your own opinion. The majority opinion seems to be that there is no evidence of any substantive contribution.